# changing a Char to the short with the same bit structure. (2's complement issue)

Tags: java, char, bit-manipulation, short

I want to Change a Char to the short with the same bit structure.
Both are 16 bits

I understand that short are 2s complement if they were 1s complement I could use

```
if a < 0 {return (short) math.abs a + 2 ^ 15;} else {return (short) a;} //right?
```

How do I do this to 2s complement negative?

I simply want to be able to manipulate the innards of a Char in the same way as I can a Integer.

If the answer is just add one I am going to become emotional :)

Comment: Can you give an example where just casting from `char` to `short` gives you an unexpected result?

Comment: `^` in Java and C-based languages is the xor operation, not power, and the syntax in your code is totally wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple solution is to do

```
char ch = ...
short s = (short) ch;
char ch2 = (char) s;
// ch == ch2
```

Perhaps you imagine it has to be more complicated than it is ;)

> I simply want to be able to manipulate the innards of a Char in the same way as I can a Integer.

In that case you don't even want a `short`, you want an `int` which is even simpler.

e.g.

```
// sum all the chars of a string
String s = "Hello World";
int sum = 0;
for(char ch: s.toCharArray())
    sum += ch;
```

> If the answer is just add one I am going to become emotional

No, even less than that. :j

BTW you can do

```
char ch = 'A';
int i = ch + 0;
int j = ch;
```

Comment: Yup.  This will have the same bit structure and everything.

Comment: for real? so characters larger than 2^15 will have negative values?

Comment: @King-Ink As a `short` yes, but as an `int` no, see my later example.